# Nagios e-mail notification

Tags: postfix, nagios

I recently installed nagios on my Debian server to be able to monitor some machines on the network but when I send the e-mail notification to the administrator I don’t receive the mail.
I set up the contact as suggested but nothing.
I have postifix and dovecot also installed and working properly.
Does anyone know how to set up nagios to send mails via postfix?

Comment: Please include the definition of the notification command. You can also try running this manually from the terminal to see if you succeed in sending an e-mail. It's possibly not strictly Nagios related, could be that postfix/dovecot/whatever is not working on that node, or Nagios does not have the correct command defined.

Comment: Thank you so much it was due to the definition of the notification command in nagios/etc/object/ command.cfg

Comment: Happy to help. If you want free karma, write up a response to your own question explaining how you fixed the issue for future googlers.